# Does Microsoft Graph change notification always send UPDATED notification for CREATED events?

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm using Microsoft Graph API change subscription to handle created/updated/deleted calendar events.

I noticed that the API always sends at least one UPDATED notification for each newly CREATED event. A quick search shows that it's normal behavior.

My question is: can this be considered a **guaranteed** behavior of the API?

If so, my plan is to only subscribe to UPDATED and DELETED notifications and treat each UPDATED event as a potential CREATED event depending on if a local copy already exists. This approach helps me deal with concurrency issues. I just want to make sure I won't miss any CREATED events this way.

Comment: Yes i think you're good above. For more information refer the docs related to all the [resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0), [how it works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview), [calendarview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-events?tabs=http) etc .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a guaranteed behavior, it is a known issue when you [use the change notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) of the user calendar event(`/users/{id}/events`).

See [Additional notifications for users:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#additional-notifications-for-users)

> Subscriptions to changes for user with `changeType` set to `updated` will also receive notifications of `changeType: updated` on **user creation** and **user soft deletion**.

Comment: Yes I saw that the documentation mentioned this for users, but not for events, so I just want to make sure.

Comment: @thankyoussd I think it also applies to this, `/events` is under the `/users` endpoint.

Comment: The link for Additional notifications for users doesn't appear to link to the issue anymore?  Is this only resolved for user creation/soft deletion, but wasn't rolled out to other aspects like events?  I am still seeing this behavior